# ssh tunnel connection refused on chromeos

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, google-cloud-platform, ssh-tunnel, google-cloud-networking

I am trying to setup an ssh tunnel to use the chrome nodejs debugger on my local system.

My nodejs app is hosted on Google Compute Engine.

These are the arguments I give on the secure shell app:

```
-L 9229:localhost:9229
```

The SSH connection works but when filling in the tunneling arguments above I keep getting following error message in a loop:

```
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

I tried using -nN in the arguments but this does not even load my command line competely.

In chrome the network targets seem to be configured properly.

[image]

These are the verbose errors I am getting:

```
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug2: channel 2: zombie
debug2: channel 2: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 2: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 9229 for localhost port 9229, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 65535 to UNKNOWN port 0, nchannels 4
debug3: channel 2: status: The following connections are open:
  #1 client-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 e[write]/0 fd 102/103/104 sock -1 cc -1)
  #3 direct-tcpip: listening port 9229 for localhost port 9229, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 65535 to UNKNOWN port 0 (t3 nr0 i0/0 o0/0 e[closed]/0 fd 106/106/-1 sock 106 cc -1)

debug3: receive packet: type 92
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug2: channel 3: zombie
debug2: channel 3: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 9229 for localhost port 9229, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 65535 to UNKNOWN port 0, nchannels 3
debug3: channel 3: status: The following connections are open:
```

How can I fix this and what do the channel errors mean.

If I change the port to e.g. `-L 9221:localhost:9229` and add localhost:9221 to the chrome target discovery settings I can reproduce the error on other ports.

Comment: How are you starting node?

Comment: @mscdex manually after the ssh connection. I just have a simple script I want to test. Can I only debug servers?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27879297/13317

Comment: @Christoph _how_ not _when_

Comment: @mscdex node --inspect test.js

Comment: it's solved I needed to use --inspect-brk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's solved I needed to use --inspect-brk to add a breakpoint so the code does not completely fire.

I also need to open 2 ssh sessions. One for port forwarding and one for coding.