# SSH tunnel and port forwarding through a bastion machine gives connection refused error

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have jupyter notebook running on a server machine that I can ssh into through a bastion machine. I want to access the notebook on my local machine.

[image]

Here is what I tried after running jupyter on the server machine:

```
ssh -f -N -L local_machine_port:server_machine_IP:server_machine_port_hosting_jupyter username@bastion_machine_ip
```

Whenever I try to access `http://localhost:local_machine_port` or `http://127.0.0.1:local_machine_port`I get

```
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Connection to port 7001 forwarding to <server ip> port <server port> requested.
debug1: channel 2: new [direct-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 7001 forwarding to <server ip> port <server port> requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [direct-tcpip]
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 2: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 7001 for <server ip> port <server port>, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 43276 to 127.0.0.1 port 7001, nchannels 4
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 7001 for <server ip> port <server port>, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 43278 to 127.0.0.1 port 7001, nchannels 3
debug1: Connection to port 7001 forwarding to 192.168.2.38 port 6006 requested.
debug1: channel 2: new [direct-tcpip]
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 2: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 7001 for <server ip> port <server port>, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 43280 to 127.0.0.1 port 7001, nchannels 3
```

What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSH -L connection successful, but localhost port forwarding not working "channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705453/ssh-l-connection-successful-but-localhost-port-forwarding-not-working-channel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add *--ip 0.0.0.0* option to  *jupyter notebook* command

You can follow the steps listed below:

```
 1. Run ssh on local machine:
     ssh -L local_machine_port:server_machine_IP:server_machine_port_hosting_jupyter username@bastion_machine_ip
 2. Run jupyter notebook on remote server:
     jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --port server_machine_port_hosting_jupyter  
 3. Open browser on localmachine:
     http://localhost:local_machine_port
```

Answer (score 0):

### edit

Sorry, I only just realized you are connecting with `ssh` to the bastion machine and not to the remote server running jupyter.

In that case you probably first need to establish a `ssh` connection to the remote server using the bastion machine, see [this answer on how to do that](https://superuser.com/a/1571653/1077836).

### original answer

Are you replacing `server_machine_IP` in your command with the external IP addres of the machine? i.e. something like

```sh
ssh -f -N -L 7001:10.45.12.34:7001 username@bastion_machine_ip
```

If so this will forward your local port to the specified port on the remote server **on its external IP address**. But if `jupyter` on that host is not listening on that IP - but only on localhost - the connection will be refused.

If jupyter is only listening to local connection you may try [@Mohammed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63767622/11932806) to let jupyter listen on the external IP. Or try the following

```sh
ssh -f -N -L 7001:localhost:7001 username@bastion_machine_ip
```

and open `http://localhost:local_machine_port` on your local machine: this will forward from the port on your local machine to the port on `localhost` **on the remote machine**, i.e. for jupyter on the remote host this will look like a connection coming from the local machine (which is the remote server).