# How can I connect my local celery to a redis queue on docker?

Tags: python, redis, celery

I have my main python program running on an EC2 with celery and a local redis queue running on it.  `CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://redis:6379`

I have set up my development environment locally on my mac but would still like to connect to that redis queue on my EC2.

Do I need to add the public DNS to the front of the local environment's `.env` (redis://redis:6379) file so celery knows how to connect to it?  I am just not sure the best way to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: As you mention this is for your local dev environment, probably best not to expose redis to the internet, and instead use an ssh tunnel... `ssh -L 6379:localhost:6379 ec2_addr` - while this ssh session is established, localhost:6379 on your dev box, is tunneled to localhost:6379 on the EC2 box.  So in your dev config, set  `CELERY_BROKER_URL=redis://localhost:6379`

Comment: Thank you v25.  Let me give this a try and get back to you.  I need to open port 22 and then check it.  Would I need to open the 6379 port as well?  The reason I ask is because I get a `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).` I think because I need to open that port.

Comment: This will work if you already have ssh access to the box, see [Connect to your Linux instance using SSH](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html).  You may also need to configure security groups for that instance to allow incoming traffic on 22.

Comment: Thank you, V25.  So, here is where I need to get my head around.  I can access ssh via the command `ssh -i "xxxx.pem" ec2-user@ec2-xxxxx.amazonaws.com`.  If I want to use the `-L` command, I still need to add my `security xxxx.pem` file?  Thank you

Comment: Ok, so after adding in the credentials, I think it worked.  `ssh -L 6379:localhost:6379 -i "xxxx.pem" ec2-user@xxxx.amazonaws.com`.  Now to see if it reaches the redis host.  Thank you

Comment: Ok.  One more question.  When I run the program, I get the error `channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 4: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
`
Does this mean I need to open the port 6379?  I can connect successfully via ssh right now

Comment: Perhaps see: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27879297/2052575).  It sounds like the redis server may not be running on localhost:6379 *on the ec2 box*.

Comment: Thank you v25, I will do a bit more work there.